# Internal USB to external ethernet?

Tags: usb, ethernet

I have a Mini-ITX build, where the mobo only has one PCIe slot, but the case has two PCI brackets. I need to use the PCIe for extra SATA ports, but I would like one or more extra ethernet ports too. The mobo does have internal USB3 onboard connectors and there are USB-Ethernet adapters, but I haven't found any internal ones.

So to be clear, what I would like, is a PCI bracket with 1-4 GbE ports, that connects directly to internal USB connector. Does this exist?

Answer (score 0):

This is not solved, but I'm adding an answer so I can add improvements until I or someone else finds something better.

This could technically be a way to solve my problem:

1) Use one of these to get two internal usb3 female-a connectors.
https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-USB-3-0-Internal-Motherboard-Header-20pin-Dual-USB-3-0-Female-Adapter-/122758653067?ef_id=CjwKCAjwza_mBRBTEiwASDWVvlNmVgHM8V6lsjsSxoHBOTA4ysxAeifgddkzoD_Azq61ObTPngDN0BoC_bIQAvD_BwE:G:s

2) Connect two of these 1xUSB3->2xEthernet to the two new usb female ports: [https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Dual-Gigabit-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B00D8XTOD0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D8XTOD0)

3) Get four ethernet extension cables, connect the male side to the double-dual-ethernet adapters, glue their female ends together on a PCI bracket and finally install that in the empty space in the chassis.

I see no reason why that wouldn't work, but it's … suboptimal.

EDIT 1: I guess I can try to find a PCIe riser with two outputs, if riser-in-riser is ok. Something like this would be ok: https://www.wiredzone.com/supermicro-components-motherboards-accessories-rsc-r2ug-2e4e8-10022062